# In Python, how should one test for the existence of a file in a path specified in an environment variable?

Tags: python, bash, path, environment-variables, system

I want to check for the existence of the following file:

```
$ANALYSISDIRECTORY/data/AnalysisDerivative/configuration.txt
```

Currently, I have a little function to ensure that a file exists:

```
def ensureFileExistence(fileName):
    log.debug("ensure existence of file {fileName}".format(
        fileName = fileName
    ))
    if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
        log.info("file {fileName} does not exist\n".format(
            fileName = fileName
        ))
        sys.exit()
```

How should I make this function more robust and able to cope with paths and paths stored in environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure you access the value of the environment variable and not its string representation you can use [os.path.expandvars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)

If the path you want to test is in a environment variable you can user [os.getenv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv)

Comment: Ah, thanks for your help on that procedure to expand the shell variables. I'm now using the test ```os.path.isfile(os.path.expandvars(fileName))```.

Comment: It may be better to use a local var to old the expanded value of the path to avoid duplicating the call to `expandvars` when printing of manipulating the path

Comment: @bvidal how about environment variables which are set in local bashrc of a user? You can see them using echo $<var_name> but not through printenv or using os.getenv

Comment: I am able to retrieve my prompt env var define in my bashrc via `os.getenv("PS1")`

Comment: @bvidal hmmm .. seems like something is fishy at my end. Does your PS1 come up when you use a printenv ?

Comment: `echo $PS1`, `printenv PS1`, `python -c "import os; print os.getenv('PS1')"` all return the same thing. Also thanks for `printenv` that I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
```

use

```
 if not os.path.exists(fileName):
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas there. In this case, I think the variable expansion approach [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28345414/1556092) by [bvidal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2003420/bvidal) makes sense.